# How to escape in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

I'm escaping two semi colons in the code below using a backslash.  I'm executing this code in SQLite Database Brower 2.0 for Mac. It keeps freezing up.  I'm guessing that is because of some syntax issue?

```
INSERT INTO question (QuestionId, QuestionText, AreaId, AnswerText)
VALUES(6019, 'Math Functions', 6, "
Added: 9/1/2011

The following is a listing of math functions available:

Power of:
double pow ( double, double )
Example:
double myvar = pow(2,4)\;
NSLog(@"%.f", myvar)\; //value is 16");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The semicolons aren't your problem, the double quotes in the `NSLog` call are:

```
NSLog(@"%.f", myvar)\; //value is 16"
       ^---^
```

Double them and SQLite will be happy:

```
NSLog(@""%.f"", myvar)\; //value is 16"
```

Or you can use single quotes around the whole thing:

```
INSERT INTO question (QuestionId, QuestionText, AreaId, AnswerText)
VALUES(6019, 'Math Functions', 6, '
Added: 9/1/2011

The following is a listing of math functions available:

Power of:
double pow ( double, double )
Example:
double myvar = pow(2,4)\;
NSLog(@"%.f", myvar)\; //value is 16');
```

Single quotes are standard for SQL strings but SQLite will let you use either single or double quotes for strings.

Answer (score 8):

In SQL, strings are always delimited with single quotes, never with double ones.

```
'Added: 9/1/2011

The following is a listing of math functions available:
[...]'
```

No characters are escaped except these single quotes (not even semicolons), and that happens by doubling:

```
SELECT 'That''s not exactly what I''m looking for...';
```

(This means that a string with only one single quote is encoded as `''''` in SQL.)

Comment: Yes, but that's apparently just an [act of resilience](http://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) towards ancient SQL statements. Double quotes are to be used for identifiers in case they conflict with keywords.

Comment: I think this answer is more usefull for any language interpritor. Thanks.